# 'Verb+Have I' or 'verb +I have'

Tags: verbs

I was writing a poem in which I used 'sinned have I' in a declarative sentence. Do I have to use 'sinned I have' instead?

Comment: No, you're free in poetry to break many rules. Be aware that your second version is even more unusual than the first, and each calls a lot of attention to itself. I would call a sentence as striking as 'Sinned have I' more exclamatory than declarative.

Comment: Sinned I have. Like Yoda I speak.

Answer (score 1):

In regular prose, all declarative sentences are composed following the strict order of a subject, a verb and a complement syntax. On the other hand, although poetry must rhyme and follows a metrical structure, the syntactical structure of the lines of a poem is not as restrictive as it is in prose. Besides, rhymes apply to the elements of style of writing and all aspects which portray to the syntactical structure rest in the constructive hands and within the artistic scope of the writer's aesthetic. On a lighter note, inverting the verb and its subject will grammatically change a declarative statement into a interrogative sentence, but the echo of poetry will discompose the sound of any ordinary prose.